# How does Google Adsense know 1 pixel of an ad has been loaded in JS?

Tags: javascript

Today I received email from google AdSense that they say they count ads impression based on 1 pixel of an ad has been loaded. How do they detect that in JavaScript?

```
AdMob counts native and interstitial impressions when at least 1 pixel of an ad appears
on a device's screen.
```

Is it possible to do that in JavaScript?

I know there is a way to detect impression by 1x1 gif pixel. However, how do they detect 1 pixel of an ad which could be either gif or png.

Comment: perhaps they count ads based on what they've sent, not what browsers have received - in other words, javascript is a cows opinion

Comment: @JaromandaX, but you cannot count on what you have sent due to lost and unpredictability of networks.

Comment: unless there's a google employee that knows and can answer your (inconsequential) question, all you'll get is educated guesses ... that's why I said perhaps. I don't know, and quite frankly I don't actually think it's important to know such minutiae to carry on a meaningful existence

Comment: @JaromandaX, that's a cows opinion.

Comment: I believe I said that already

Answer (score 0):

You can specify onload function on image tag which will be called when image is loaded. Also they can put their logic in server as well so that when request to load that image comes, they will know have been called.

Comment: but onload function will only be called when the full image has been loaded, not one pixel. right?

Comment: that full image is only 1 pixel image. its 1x1 image.

Comment: but according to their statement, "1 pixel of an ad" that means it's part of the actual ads not external 1x1 image